# Running exchange in read-only mode

Tags: exchange, exchange-migration, read-only

After a move to new servers, an old exchange 5.5 server must be switched to read-only operation mode.

I have tried putting limits in  "message delivery->properties->Defaults" sending message size : 1kb, receiving message size : 1kb.

After seeing it did not work, I put limits in "mailbox store properties->limits" but still mail can be sent and received.

How can I make exchange read-only?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there's a way that Microsoft intended to let that happen. As you describe the issue, it would make much more sense to move all mailboxes, public folders, GAL generation, etc away from the older Exchange server and then decommission it.

That said, removing all Receive Connectors and Send Connectors from the Exchange server, would effectively stop it from receiving or sending mail.

You could still delete mail by logging into an OWA or Outlook mailbox with Full Access permissions, though. It's possible to set permissions for a mailbox to read only, though. [link text](http://exchangeshare.wordpress.com/2009/07/07/how-to-setup-read-only-mailbox-in-exchange-20032007/)

So the next step would be to create an account that has read-only permissions to all mailboxes. A command such as the following should do the trick:

```
get-mailbox -server "readonlyexchangeserver" | add-mailboxpermission -accessrights ReadPermission -user ReadOnlyUser
```

Then remove all access permissions for the original users using the following command (syntax here [link text](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125264%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx))

```
get-mailbox -server "readonlyexchangeserver" | set-casmailbox -activesyncenabled $false -imapenabled $false -mapienabled $false -owaenabled $false -popenabled $false
```

You could also remove each user's permissions to their assigned mailboxes instead of the previous command.

If you wish to have a much easier time of this, you could simply export each mailbox into a PST, mark them as read-only, and review the mailboxes from there.